# How do I view response codes when posting to an API using a PHP function?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, http-headers

Are there some good guidelines, because I cannot find proper information online?

I've been following the instructions of an API's documentation.
When there is an order made in WordPress, I want to post my data to an external API.
For the most part, everything is going well. However, how am I supposed to see response codes?

For example, I'm supposed to be getting a response like this:

```
{
  "response":52
}
```

I did a lot of googling, and it sounds like most HTTP responses are shown inside the browser's developer tools. However, it sounds like in my particular case, this is server side.
Are these responses logged on the server?
Am I supposed to add any code that helps me see responses during testing?

Here's an example of a basic code I'm using for the API:

```
<?php

add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'create_new_external_order', 10, 2);

function create_new_external_order($order_id, $order) {
    function sendRequest($url, $type = 'get', $params = [], $json = true) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

        if ($type == 'post' || $type == 'put') {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

            if ($json) {
                $params = json_encode($params);

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
                    'Content-Type: application/json',
                    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($params)
                ]);

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
            }
            else {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
            }
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Poster (http://my-api-base-url.com)');

        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $data;
    }

    $url = 'https://my-api-base-url.com/api/blahblahblah'
        . '?format=json'
        . '&token=xxxxxxxxx';

    $incoming_order = [
        'spot_id'   => 1,
        'phone'     => '+0123456789',
        'products'  => [
            [
                'product_id' => 1,
                'count'      => 5
            ],
        ],
    ];

    $data = sendRequest($url, 'post', $incoming_order);
}

?>
```

Comment: _"For example, I'm supposed to be getting a response like this:"_ - that doesn't look like it had anything to do with HTTP headers to begin with. You are getting a JSON data structure in the response _body_ - so decode that JSON, and access the properties/elements of the resulting data structure.

Answer (score 1):

To handle response codes from the external API within your PHP code, you can modify the sendRequest function to capture and handle HTTP response codes. Here's an updated version of your code with comments explaining the changes:

```
function sendRequest($url, $type = 'get', $params = [], $json = true) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

    if ($type == 'post' || $type == 'put') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

        if ($json) {
            $params = json_encode($params);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($params)
            ]);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        } else {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
        }
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Poster (http://my-api-base-url.com)');

    // Execute the request and capture both response data and HTTP response code
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    // Close the cURL session
    curl_close($ch);

    // Return both response data and HTTP response code
    return ['data' => $data, 'http_code' => $http_code];
}

// Usage example:
$response = sendRequest($url, 'post', $incoming_order);

// Check the HTTP response code
if ($response['http_code'] == 200) {
    // Successful request
    $responseData = json_decode($response['data'], true);
    // Process $responseData as needed
} else {
    // Handle the error
    echo "Error: HTTP response code " . $response['http_code'];
}
```

With this modification, the sendRequest function now returns an array containing both the response data and the HTTP response code. In your main code, you can then check the HTTP response code and handle any errors accordingly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy